# Regexp \\text{vars}(\([:ascii:]+\)) -> |\1| doesn't work

Tags: regular-expressions

Why doesn't this regexp work when I do `C-M-%`? I need to replace exactly these strings:
`\text{vars}(\vp) -> |\vp|`
`\text{vars}(\vp') -> |\vp|`
I don't have anything else of the form `\text{vars}*`, so I used
`\\text{vars}(\([:ascii:]+\)) -> |\1|` and got `Replaced 0 occurrences`. What's wrong?

Comment: You can use `M-x re-builder` to test complicated regexps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Character classes* need to be used within a *character alternative*. i.e.

```
[[:ascii:]]
```

If you just have `[:ascii:]` then you're saying "any one of `:`, `a`, `s`, `c`, or `i`".

That's probably not quite what you want either, though -- `)` is an ascii character, after all, so (depending on your input) you run the risk of the closing paren getting swallowed in the `[[:ascii:]]+` pattern. (e.g. if there was a subsequent closing paren on the same line.)

If you simply want to match everything until the first closing parenthesis, you would use a *non-greedy* operator, like so:

```
(\([[:ascii:]]+?\))
```

or if you know that it's safe to grab *whatever* is between the parens, you could more simply write:

```
(\(.+?\))
```

or perhaps you want `(\([^']+?\)'?)` ? (I've become a little unsure of the criteria after re-reading the question... if you want to replace only the *exact* two strings you've indicated, a non-regexp replace probably makes more sense...)